# Excel SUMPRODUCT with dynamic column range to sum

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, multiple-conditions

```
       A        B     C     D  
1  Department  Jan   Feb   Mar  
2  Marketing   100   200   300  
3  R&D         150   250   350  
4  Marketing   300   400   500
```

I have a sample file like the above table.

The SUMPRODUCT formula below only sums the specific rows and column, which is row 2 to 20 and column B to C for summing

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A20="Marketing")*(B2:C20))
```

Actual formula (from comments):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(BW!$A$3:$AE$3,MATCH(C$35,BW!$1:$1,0)+MATCH("JAN 2016",BW!$F$2:$R$2,0)-1):INDEX(BW!$A$108:$AE$108,MATCH(C$35,BW!$1:$1,0)+MATCH("A‌​UG 2016",BW!$F$2:$R$2,0)-1)*(BW!$B$3:$B$108=$E$1))
```

My questions, is there a way to make SUMPRODUCT dynamic, in a sense, it knows the first row to take will be 2nd and ends at 20.

As for the dynamic column to sum, it'll depend on the criteria. i.e. if the criteria is Feb and Mar, it'll take column C2:D20...again, the row is dynamic as well.

Comment: Where is the formula supposed to get *Feb* and *Mar* from? Where is it currently getting *Jan* and *Feb* from?

Comment: @Jeeped Currently, this is my formula...not as the above.

`=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(BW!$A$3:$AE$3,MATCH(C$35,BW!$1:$1,0)+MATCH("JAN 2016",BW!$F$2:$R$2,0)-1):INDEX(BW!$A$108:$AE$108,MATCH(C$35,BW!$1:$1,0)+MATCH("AUG 2016",BW!$F$2:$R$2,0)-1)*(BW!$B$3:$B$108=$E$1))`

Comment: It looks like you actually typed `"A‌​UG 2016"` into the worksheet and didn't use a proper date formatted as `mmm yyyy`.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn your range into a table called `Table1` then the following should work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Department]="Marketing")*(INDIRECT("Table1[[Jan]:["&VLOOKUP("*",Table1[#Headers],COLUMNS(Table1),FALSE)&"]]")))
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the SUMPRODUCT dynamic we can use INDEX/MATCH to find the extents of the data.

Then all that is need is to put the months wanted listed in one cell, I used I7

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1:INDEX(1:1,MATCH("ZZZ",1:1)),I7)))*($A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A))="Marketing")*B2:INDEX(A:DD,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A),MATCH("ZZZ",1:1)))
```

The `INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A))` will find the last cell with text in Column A, and use that to set the extent of the dataset.

For the Last column we use `INDEX(1:1,MATCH("ZZZ",1:1))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to work with a ListObject (aka *Structured*) table, then a dynamic named range would certainly help.

1. Go to Formulas, Defined Names, Name Manager and when the Name Manager dialog opens, click New.
2. Give your defined name range a unique name; I've chosen **Departments**.
3. Leave the Scope as workbook and use the following formula for the Refers to:
    
    `=BW!$A$1:INDEX(BW!$A:$M, MATCH("zzz",BW!$A:$A ), MATCH(1E+99,BW!$1:$1 ))`
    
   Columns A:M will cover a Department column and Jan through Dec. **Note that Jan 2016-Dec 2016 are real dates (e.g. `1/1/2016` to `12/1/2016`) formatted as `mmm yyyy`.**
4. You should end up with the following dynamic named range:

[image: departments]

Now you can 'shape' the sections of the defined range using [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pairs.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(Departments, 0, 1)=Q3)*
            (INDEX(Departments, 0, MATCH(R3, INDEX(Departments, 1, 0), 0)):
             INDEX(Departments, 0, MATCH(S3, INDEX(Departments, 1, 0), 0))))
```

[image: departments_FORMULA]